# Suggestion for a new flag

Tags: discussion, flagging

So often there are questions that are answered in the comments. Standard MSE policy is that we post the comment as an answer in the form of a community wiki so that the question can be accepted by the OP.

However sometimes the OP basically does a "hit-and-run" and never reappears again leaving the question permanently "unanswered" (ie not accepted). Seeing that this is sometimes a problem, would it be useful to consider a "no longer relevant" flag to close such questions? Maybe we could impose some guidelines as well on when such a flag should be used.

EDIT: Actually I looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126007/evaluating-the-composition-of-a-single-integer-from-multiple-smaller-values) I see Martin Sleziak's point (refer to comments). Can this be an example that falls under no longer relevant?

EDIT: Some questions don't have enough information in them to be answered. However flagging it as not a question doesn't seem entirely appropriate either. One such example is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94152/modular-form-holomorphic-at-cusps). A new "no longer relevant" flag would be appropriate for such circumstances, I think. I tried flagging this question as not a real question but my flag was disputed. This would remove a grey area in flagging.

Comment: Are questions without acceptances the problem, or is it questions without an upvoted answer? I thought the Community user only bumped the latter.

Comment: Sometimes it's not just the community user. Sometimes the questions that have answers turn up when filtering for unanswered questions.

Comment: Ah, I never do that.

Comment: Probably this is also about questions which are unclear and the OP did not give clarification even after being asked in comments. So it is kind of stalemate - such quetsion cannot be answered, since it is not clear what the question is asking.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I agree that is a problem. Could that be covered under "not a question" though?

Answer (score 9):

There's no need to close such questions, while having the OP accept an answer is nice, it is not necessary. If any answer has a score of +1 or higher, the system considers it answered, so it won't e.g. appear in the unanswered tab anymore.

Just upvote such a CW answer to at least +1 if you see one.

Comment: What if there's one upvote and one downvote. Is it considered unanswered still?

Comment: @Eugene The score is important, not the number of upvotes itself. A post with one upvote and one downvote has a score of zero, it wouldn't count as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the "unanswered question" filter, myself, so I think such a flag might be useful, in principle. In practice, though, it is (of course) impossible to say whether a given user will *never* appear again (only that they haven't yet posted a question, answer, or comment since their last), so I suspect such a flag would prove problematic in some situations.

Comment: That's why some guidelines should be in order.

Comment: Agreed, if such a flag were to be implemented. That said, I wonder how a list of such guidelines could be assured to be complete? (Or even "representatively complete"...if that makes any sense.)

Comment: A year makes sense right? So if we were to shrink that lower bound, what would it be?

Comment: It makes sense to *me*, yes (and evidently to you), but on the other hand, I've visited the site daily (and have been active nearly as often) since I obtained an ID, so perhaps my "sense" is an uncharacteristic view of what is "reasonable" insofar as frequency of contribution/activity. I'm certainly open to discussion on the matter--that's why I stuck in my 2 cents--I'm simply cautioning against haste.